# Sitecore setting up goals

Tags: sitecore, goal-tracking

I'm currently searching if there's a way of associating goals in to a button without using the Sitecore Forms, is that possible without any additional code?

Currently trying and searching if there's a way to associate goals with a button.

Comment: Please only tag the version of software that you are using, rather than multiple ones, as the solution could be dependent on the version.

Answer (score 3):

You can associate goals with items and Sitecore Forms, see the most recent documentation [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/103/sitecore-experience-platform/associate-a-goal-with-an-item.html).

If you would like to trigger a goal by clicking on a hyperlink or a button then there is a workaround with a `sc_trk` URL param.

You simply need to append `sc_trk={Goal GUID or Goal Name}` to your URL and it will call all the necessary functions to trigger the goal that it refers to.